# ipython in cygwin does not have autocomplete

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin, ipython

I did the following

1. Install python (2.7) on windows using official setup file from python.org
2. Created a virtual env using the same interpreter
3. Installed ipython in the virtual env

When I run ipython from windows commandline, everything works good. I get the colors and autocomplete. But when I run inside cygwin bash, there are no colors and autocomplete does not work. I also installed `pyreadline` package in the same virtual env but didn't fix it. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Not just ipython. Most native windows programs (especially the interactive ones) don't work good in cygwin terminal.

Possible options:

1. Install cygwin version of the program. Python/ipython can be installed inside cygwin
2. Run in dos/power shell
3. Start bash in powershell and start the native program within it.
4. Install Ubuntu or other linux on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)